# Stop Apache being controlled by Mountain Lion Server

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, osx-mountain-lion

Before I installed OS X Server through the App Store, everything was working fine. I had a number of virtual hosts, some of which were proxy passing to other servers on the network. I also had Phusion Passenger installed and working great.

But, when I installed it, it obliterated all my previous configs, and I can't get it back to the way it was.

I've tried editing the configs in:

- `/etc/apache2/`
- `/private/etc/apache2/`
- `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/`

But none of them seem to make a difference.

Can I have Mountain Lion server with all its benefits of AFP and Time Machine for multiple machines without it messing with my Apache configs?

I've tried turning off the 'web' service in Server and doing `sudo apachectl start`, but I'm greeted by a message saying I need to turn on web sharing in the Server App to do anything.

Can anyone help me get it back to how it was before without uninstalling Server, as I'm using it for VPN, File Sharing, Time Machine, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Can I have Mountain Lion server with all its benefits of AFP and Time Machine for multiple machines without it messing with my Apache configs?`

Sure. You have to install your own Apache, PHP, Passenger, etc. to do it though.

Apple "owns" the Apache that ships with OS X. They can (and will) do whatever they please with it, and this may (and probably will) break your configuration from time to time.

If you want to protect yourself from that you need to install your own copies of the necessary components, in a location that does not conflict with Apple's versions.
You also need to create your own `launchd` startup scripts (or manually start your services at reboot), and make sure Apple's versions of these programs are not running to avoid creating conflicts.

---

`Can anyone help me get it back to how it was before without uninstalling Server, as I'm using it for VPN, File Sharing, Time Machine, etc.?`

Do you have backups?
If so, restore from them.  If not, you're pretty much out of luck -- rebuilding your configuration will be faster/easier than trying to figure out how to unwind everything that went on when you installed OS X Server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Simply deleting the Server app got me back to where I was before, I was just hoping that OS X Server wouldn't break as much as it did.

Comment: @Alfo my experience with OS X (any variety) as a production server system have been less than stellar. If you're doing anything other than using Apple's apps exactly as Apple intended you're in for headaches...